# Format Exception: Unexpected Character (at character 1)Instance of 'VerifyData'

Tags: flutter

Why does this code give me this error? In the emulator, I have this problem Format Exception: Unexpected Character (at character 1)Instance of 'VerifyData'. I don't know resolve of this.

```
static VerifyData? fromObject(Object? data) {
    try {
      if (data != null) {
        var jsonObject = json.decode(data.toString());
        return VerifyData.fromJson(jsonObject);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

this is class VerifyData and json. what's wrong in this my code? because I think it is in accordance with the contents of the API that I have made

```
class VerifyData {
  int? id;
  String? user;
  String? name;
  String? level;
  String? photo;
  String? email;
  String? phone;
  String? address;
  String? time;
  String? v;
  int? iat;
  int? exp;

  VerifyData(
      {this.id,
      this.user,
      this.name,
      this.level,
      this.photo,
      this.email,
      this.phone,
      this.address,
      this.time,
      this.v,
      this.iat,
      this.exp});

  VerifyData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    user = json['user'];
    name = json['name'];
    level = json['level'];
    photo = json['photo'];
    email = json['email'];
    phone = json['phone'];
    address = json['address'];
    time = json['time'];
    v = json['v'];
    iat = json['iat'];
    exp = json['exp'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['user'] = this.user;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['level'] = this.level;
    data['photo'] = this.photo;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['phone'] = this.phone;
    data['address'] = this.address;
    data['time'] = this.time;
    data['v'] = this.v;
    data['iat'] = this.iat;
    data['exp'] = this.exp;
    return data;
  }
```

I/flutter ( 5881): Data : {"id":1,"user":"admin","name":"Admin","level":"employee","photo":null,"email":"admin@gmail.com","phone":null,"address":"Jl. Asem Daerah","time":"2022-10-11T02:34:55.138Z","v":"p","iat":1122355694,"exp":1122259294}

Comment: can you add your VerifyData class and show us your jsonObject ?

Comment: yes I can, I already edit my post @manhtuan21

Comment: okay just one more thing, after line  if (data != null), can you add print(data) and let me see it

Comment: I already add print(data)

Comment: seem like you print wrong, it is Exception message, not data

Comment: okay sorry, I already update

Comment: I have checked your code and run on my simulator, it 's correct. It seem like Exception happen somewhere else, or you can check this thread https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32841

Comment: It seems that the problem is here `var jsonObject = json.decode(data.toString());` what is the type of the data when you receive it? can you `print(data.runtimeType);` before that line

Comment: I/flutter ( 8136): String

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this out: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json